# A man invests an amount of $ ₹ 15860 $ in the names of his three sons A, B & C in such a way that they get the same interest..

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

A man invests an amount of $   ₹ 15860 $ in the names of his three sons A, B & C in such a way that they get the same interest after $2, 3$ & $4$ years respectively. If the rate of simple interest is $ 5  $% , then the ratio of amounts invested among A, B & C is?

I put the Simple Interest as ₹ $\hspace{3 pt}   x $ (given) in all the cases, supposed the three principles as  $ y $ , $ z $ and $ (15860-y-z) $ respectively and then tried to find the value of S.I. (x) by equating them, but failed!

(Note: ₹ - Rupee, Indian Currency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let a,b and c the ratio of what the three sons get first. Then pay the interest for the capital of every son. All the results must be equal:

$a \cdot 15,860 \cdot (1.05)^2 =D \quad (1)$

$b \cdot 15,860 \cdot (1.05)^3 =D \quad (2)$

$c \cdot 15,860 \cdot (1.05)^4 =D\quad (3)$

And the sum of a,b and c ist one:

$a+b+c=1 \quad (4) $

So you have 4 equations and 4 variables. This system can be solved. You can start with dividing equation $(2)$ by equation $(1)$.

greetings,

calculus

Comment: What is $ 1.05 $ ???

Comment: @Virek It is the factor which you need, when you compound.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ be the total amount of money and $x$, $y$ and $z$ be the amount of money each of the sons get ($x+y+z=a$). The rate of interest is $r=1.05$. Then, we want to solve the system
$$
x+y+z=a\\
x r^4 = y r^3 = z r^2
$$
Substituting the $y$ and $z$ form the second equation in the first:
$$
x(1 +  r^1+r^2)=a\\
x \frac{1-r}{1-r^3}=a\\
x=a\frac{1-r^3}{1-r}
$$